# Suppose $X(u,v)=(u-2v,u+3v)=(x,y)$ and $F(x,y)=\left( f(x,y),g(x,y) \right)$ with $f(x,y),\: g(x,y)$ continuously differentiable.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose $X(u,v)=(u-2v,u+3v)=(x,y)$ and $F(x,y)=\left( f(x,y),g(x,y) \right)$ with $f(x,y),\: g(x,y)$ continuously differentiable. Express the derivative of $F(X)(u,v)$ in terms of derivatives of $x$ and $y$.

I am confused about the exercise. I don't know if I need to do the following:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(u-2v\right)= 1\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\left(u-2v\right)=-2 \\
\frac{d}{du}\left(u+3v\right)=1 \\
\frac{d}{dv}\left(u+3v\right)=3
\end{align*}

How did this come about:

\begin{align*}
F(X)(u, v)=\left( f(u-2v,\: u+3v),\: g(u-2v,\: u+3v) \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Your formulation is very confusing. Do you mean “express the (partial) derivatives of $F(X(u,v))$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ in terms of derivatives of $F(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$”? In that case, it's just the chain rule.

Comment: You could show how it is done. I am still confused on how to use the chain rule for this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define $H(u,v)=(F\circ X)(u,v)=\big(f(X(u,v)), g(X(u,v))\big)^\intercal=(p(u,v),q(u,v))^\intercal$

By the chain rule
$$\begin{align}
H'(u,v)&= F'(X(u,v))X'(u,v)\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} \partial_xf(X(u,v)) & \partial_yf(X(u,v))\\
\partial_x g(X(u,v)) & \partial_yg(X(u,v))
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2\\
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_xf(X(u,v))+\partial_yf(X(u,v) & -2\partial_xf(X(u,v))+3\partial_yf(X(u,v))\\
\partial_xg(X(u,v))+\partial_yg(X(u,v) & -2\partial_xg(X(u,v))+3\partial_yg(X(u,v))
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

From here, you can read out what $\partial_xp$, $\partial_yp$, $\partial_xq$ and $\partial_yq$ are, i.e. what $H'(u,v)$ is.